# Exception opening *.storyboard file in Visual Studio 2013 with OS X via VirtualBox

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I got exception below every time when I try to open *.storyboard file in VS 2013, and am never able to open it. However, I can deploy Xamarin.iOS projects in VS to iPhone.

Below is my system details:

- Windows 7 host, OS X 10.9.5 guest via VirtualBox
- I can ping guest from host, vice versa.
- I can deploy Xamarin.iOS project in VS to iPhone.
- Windows firewall is disabled.

Windows Settings

- Windows 7, VS 2013, Xamarin 3.9.2, Xamarin.iOS   8.6.1.0,

Mac Settings

- Mac OS X 10.9.5, Xcode 6.1.1, Xamarin.iOS 8.6.1.20, Xamarin Studio 5.7.1

Exception below (in VS):

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ServerIO.Server_Post(String command, MemoryStream ms, IDictionary`2 queryVariables)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ExecuteRawPostCommand>b__11()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteCommandTask[TResult](BuildServerCommand command, Func`1 code, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteRawPostCommand(String commandName, MemoryStream stream, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.VSBuildServerClient.DesignerSendPayload(MemoryStream payload, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Designer.DesignerRemoteRequests.<>c__DisplayClass3.<SendPayload>b__0(VSBuildServerClient client)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.BuildServer.<>c__DisplayClass88`1.<RunOnlyIfConnected>b__86()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ServerIO.Server_Post(String command, MemoryStream ms, IDictionary`2 queryVariables)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ExecuteRawPostCommand>b__11()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteCommandTask[TResult](BuildServerCommand command, Func`1 code, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteRawPostCommand(String commandName, MemoryStream stream, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.VSBuildServerClient.DesignerSendPayload(MemoryStream payload, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Designer.DesignerRemoteRequests.<>c__DisplayClass3.<SendPayload>b__0(VSBuildServerClient client)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.BuildServer.<>c__DisplayClass88`1.<RunOnlyIfConnected>b__86()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---


Contents of C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Log\12.0\iOSDesigner.2015-02-14__11-59-42.log:
[2015-02-14 12:04:45.7] INFO: Starting full reload...
[2015-02-14 12:04:45.7] INFO: Reloading: Serialization took 3ms
[2015-02-14 12:07:22.1] ERROR: EnsureSession (counter 0): System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ServerIO.Server_Post(String command, MemoryStream ms, IDictionary`2 queryVariables)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ExecuteRawPostCommand>b__11()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteCommandTask[TResult](BuildServerCommand command, Func`1 code, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteRawPostCommand(String commandName, MemoryStream stream, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.VSBuildServerClient.DesignerSendPayload(MemoryStream payload, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Designer.DesignerRemoteRequests.<>c__DisplayClass3.<SendPayload>b__0(VSBuildServerClient client)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.BuildServer.<>c__DisplayClass88`1.<RunOnlyIfConnected>b__86()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ServerIO.Server_Post(String command, MemoryStream ms, IDictionary`2 queryVariables)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ExecuteRawPostCommand>b__11()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteCommandTask[TResult](BuildServerCommand command, Func`1 code, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteRawPostCommand(String commandName, MemoryStream stream, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.VSBuildServerClient.DesignerSendPayload(MemoryStream payload, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Designer.DesignerRemoteRequests.<>c__DisplayClass3.<SendPayload>b__0(VSBuildServerClient client)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.BuildServer.<>c__DisplayClass88`1.<RunOnlyIfConnected>b__86()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

[2015-02-14 12:07:22.2] ERROR: Unexpected exception while reloading XML for MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerItem[]
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ServerIO.Server_Post(String command, MemoryStream ms, IDictionary`2 queryVariables)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ExecuteRawPostCommand>b__11()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteCommandTask[TResult](BuildServerCommand command, Func`1 code, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteRawPostCommand(String commandName, MemoryStream stream, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.VSBuildServerClient.DesignerSendPayload(MemoryStream payload, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Designer.DesignerRemoteRequests.<>c__DisplayClass3.<SendPayload>b__0(VSBuildServerClient client)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.BuildServer.<>c__DisplayClass88`1.<RunOnlyIfConnected>b__86()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ServerIO.Server_Post(String command, MemoryStream ms, IDictionary`2 queryVariables)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ExecuteRawPostCommand>b__11()
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteCommandTask[TResult](BuildServerCommand command, Func`1 code, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at MonoTouch.Tools.Utilities.BuildServerClient.ExecuteRawPostCommand(String commandName, MemoryStream stream, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.VSBuildServerClient.DesignerSendPayload(MemoryStream payload, IDictionary`2 queryVariables, Boolean propagateExceptions)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Designer.DesignerRemoteRequests.<>c__DisplayClass3.<SendPayload>b__0(VSBuildServerClient client)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Utilities.BuildServer.<>c__DisplayClass88`1.<RunOnlyIfConnected>b__86()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

Xamarin log when opening the .storyboard in VS displays below :

```
.. I omitted it for brevity
[14-Feb-2015 13:08:11] Request handled in 48.955ms
[14-Feb-2015 13:08:14] Request handled in 13.773ms
[14-Feb-2015 13:08:14] Request handled in 26.296ms
[14-Feb-2015 13:08:17] Request handled in 19.141ms
[14-Feb-2015 13:08:17] Request handled in 14.455ms
[14-Feb-2015 13:08:20] Request handled in 12.177ms
.. I omitted it for brevity
```

The command below shows the SpringBoard process is NOT restarting (on Mac X)

```
sudo newproc.d 2> /dev/null | grep SpringBoard
```

Result from the command above

```
2015 Feb 14 12:08:17 540 <461> 32b xpcproxy_sim com.apple.SpringBoard
2015 Feb 14 12:08:27 542 <461> 32b xpcproxy_sim com.apple.SpringBoard
2015 Feb 14 12:08:32 544 <461> 32b xpcproxy_sim com.apple.SpringBoard
2015 Feb 14 12:08:38 545 <461> 32b xpcproxy_sim com.apple.SpringBoard
2015 Feb 14 12:08:43 547 <461> 32b xpcproxy_sim com.apple.SpringBoard
2015 Feb 14 12:08:48 548 <461> 32b xpcproxy_sim com.apple.SpringBoard
... I omitted these for brevity
2015 Feb 14 12:28:14 934 <601> 32b xpcproxy_sim com.apple.SpringBoard
2015 Feb 14 12:28:27 939 <601> 32b xpcproxy_sim com.apple.SpringBoard
...  I omitted these for brevity
```

I came across the links below, but cannot fix it:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25504/intermittent-ios-designer-500-internal-server-error-caused-by-xcode-6/p1
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25504/intermittent-ios-designer-500-internal-server-error-caused-by-xcode-6/p2

Comment: Have the similar problem using VS2013 and Xamarin Studio on Mac crashes as well.